# How can google analytics be integrated in a desktop application (MAC)..?

Tags: macos

Could anyone help or refer how it can be done..I searched over the net and what i felt is that its only for mobile and websites.

Answer (score 1):

It's for websites. Many of the concepts of web analytics (number of pages viewed for example) don't even make any sense on a desktop app, because they're not organized like a web page.

Comment: Not necessarily: Apple Help is just a bundle of web pages

Comment: There are other use cases which could make it very useful. Consider google campaigns driving traffic to a site, resulting in a desktop app being installed, and subsequent purchases and other 'page like' actions via the app. Google provides the Google measurement protocol for cases like this, but it would be a huge advantage to be able to obtain the cookie based client-id's etc for calls using the gmp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Google analytics data from an analytics account Google provides a [data export API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html).

If you want to track your native application then as Catfish_Man (great name btw!) said, it is not really possible. That isn't totally true, as you could fake it, but the paradigm is so different that you would be better off creating you own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see this library for GA on desktops

http://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics doesn't provide a native Mac app integration, but you can use the [Measurement Protocol Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to send raw data to your GA property from your account.

Just create a mobile app property and then start sending raw GA events using HTTP. There are couple Obj-C wrappers available like https://github.com/swisspol/GARawTracker or https://github.com/stephenlind/SimpleCocoaGoogleAnalytics.