# Using google analytics android for desktop application

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am on the lookout for doing analytics for a desktop application written in Java. I came across two services viz: TrackerBird and DesktopMetrics , but for a small time developer like me , those services are not affordable.

Google analytics has android support. So I was wondering if I could use the same in the desktop application which is on Java.I am looking for a headsup if anyone has implemented the same and tips on how to proceed on using GA on desktop.

[the SO link here says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619848/how-can-google-analytics-be-integrated-in-a-desktop-application-mac) , but I think it can be done.

[Here is the link of google code on using GA in android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/) , says it should bind to an application context. I was wondering if I could hack it to work in a desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Google supported library for GA on desktop Java.  The Google Analytics Android library has a lot of dependencies on Android infrastructure (for extracting basic user information, maintaining persistent state, and tracking application lifetime).  But, since GA just boils down to HTTP image requests, it should be possible for a desktop Java app to mimic those.  I have not used it, but this library looks like what you want: http://code.google.com/p/jgoogleanalytics/

For more details and other useful links see [Manually sending data to Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653239/manually-sending-data-to-google-analytics/12658259#12658259)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Mixpanel?  It gives you 25,000 to 175,000 free data points a month and has a Java integration library:

https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/java